# Iterating through two lists and return indices

Tags: python, list, loops

I created a habit tracker app and one of the functions is to return the longest uninterrupted streak of done habits. If there are two or more habits with the same streak length, I want to return all of them. Therefore I saved the habit IDs in an `id_list` and the respective streak lengths in the `streak_length_list`.

Let me give you an example:

```
id_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
streak_length_list = [2, 5, 6, 6, 6, 1]
longest_streak = max(streak_length_list)
longest_streak_ids = []
```

How can I iterate through the `id_list` and the `streak_length_list` simultaneously and append the respective ID to the `longest_streak_id` list if its length equals the `longest_streak` value?

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: The expected output would be ```longest_streak_ids = [3, 4, 5]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over both lists, only over `streak_length_list` and use `enumerate` to get the value and index of all items. If the value equals to `longest_streak` use the index to get the id from `id_list`

```
longest_streak_ids = [id_list[i] for i, x in enumerate(streak_length_list) if x == longest_streak]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the lists:

```
longest_streak_ids = [i for i, x in zip(id_list, streak_length_list) if x == longest_streak]

Out[15]: [3, 4, 5]
```